# Building LiquidFun(Box2D) results in an error

Tags: c++, cmake, makefile, build, box2d

I am currently trying to build LiquidFun, but I get the following error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:165 (set_target_properties):
  set_target_properties Can not find target to add properties to:
  Freetype::Freetype


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:165 (set_target_properties):
  set_target_properties Can not find target to add properties to:
  Fontconfig::Fontconfig
...
```

Here is the repo: `https://github.com/google/liquidfun` and here are the build steps:

```
sudo apt-get install cmake
sudo apt-get install libglapi-mesa
sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev#

cd liquidfun/Box2D
cmake -G'Unix Makefiles'
make
```

`http://google.github.io/liquidfun/Building/html/md__building_linux.html`.

Does someone know why this happens?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The project [redefines](https://github.com/google/liquidfun/blob/master/liquidfun/Box2D/CMakeLists.txt#L108) standard `add_library` function and expects it to be called only for "real" libraries. However, modern CMake modules and packages are heavily use IMPORTED targets, and `Freetype::Freetype` is an example of such targets. As a fast fix you could try to remove that redefinition of `add_library` function and see whether it will work.